# Chart format corrupted or size is wrong when I copy from Excel 2013 to Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts

When I copy charts from Excel 2003 or Excel 2013 to Word 2013 the charts are corrupted:

1. the fonts are too big so the titles and legend text is a mess.
2. If I don't want the chart to update in Word when I change the Excel spreadsheet I have to copy as a picture.  Then it comes across as much too large (off the page) and I have to scale every chart every time.  It's time consuming and difficult to get all chart to be the same size.

How can I get around these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try this option and check your outcome. Use "Keep Source Formatting & Embedded Workbook (K)" Paste Special option in Word. Copy the chart from the Excel and on the Word doc, right click and choose Paste > "Keep Source Formatting & Embedded Workbook (K)". This will keep the source format while you copy and paste the chart.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I've been doing.  if I do it that way then the chart in Word keeps updating each time I update Excel.  if I post the picture, the size is wrong.  If I use your first method from Excel 2003 files the chart is a complete mess with fonts too large.  if I update the chart for 2003 format to Excel 2013 befoire hand then I lose all the colours and formats.  The format of the default charts in Excel 2013 is poor - the colours of the lines are indistinct and lack contrast and borders and lines are a mess. It is a very time consuming job to reformat them.